# How to enable the ps -ux option on busybox?

Tags: busybox

I have stripped down busy box for my embedded linux.Currently the busy box supports only ps -w option.

I need to sample an application for its CPU and Memory usage and the sample should be atleast 5 per sec. Top command gives 1 sample per sec.

I am currently using ps -ux to get the CPU and Memory usage for this particular process and using vmstat and meminfo to get the overall CPU and memory usage. I am straightaway redirecting the info obtained from "ps -ux" ,"meminfo","vmstat" to a file and later on I will parse this file to see the trend for this particular process with respect to overall CPU and Memory Usage thats how I am getting 3-5 samples per second.

The problem is I am not able to enable the "ps -ux" on my busy box.
How to enable the ps -ux option on busy box which has a stripped down linux version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I see here is to build a needed version of *ps* from [source code](http://procps.sourceforge.net/). Of course, do not forget that you need to cross-compile it as it's for embedded system that I assume runs on ARM or other non x86 architecture. After that simply replace binary on your embedded system with the newly built one (don't forget backup, just in case).

Comment: Thanks for answering, but that's the thing I wanted to avoid.

Comment: @spanky please let us know if you succeed. Once I have faced the same problem, but my solution was to redesign a script to avoid the need of *ps*.

Comment: Sure I will let you know IF I SUCCEED.

Comment: I just cross-compiled procps for ARM.The only dependency seemed to be ncurses (which I also cross-compiled).

Comment: @itisravi have you actually tested it? Are there no runtime issues?

Comment: Yes I did. Just export the path to libproc-3.2.8.so to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Comment: @itisravi I've never cross-compiled on Windows for Linux, could you post some quick instructions?  See my question here: http://serverfault.com/questions/505491/how-to-monitor-cpu-usage-on-a-device-running-embedded-linux-and-busybox

Comment: A co-worker just pointed me to this article on setting up the ARM-GCC toolchain on Windows: http://dev.frozeneskimo.com/notes/setting_up_arm_gcc_windows/

Comment: @Alan Neither have I. I would recommend cross-compiling it on a Linux machine (which is what I did).

Comment: Haha, this defeats using busybox in the first place :-). If you really do not have a choice over the base image and want to hack your way, your could copy a binary bundle of your choice produced with the GNU Guix package manager (e.g., `guix pack procps`, which are portable across GNU/Linux-based systems.

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to read whatever process statistics you need out of the kernel's `/proc` virtual directory. `/proc/PID/stat` has [all kinds of good stuff](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/proc.html), and you can read it as often as you want.